# Cuando extraigo un componente de typescript, getInitialProps ya no funciona

Tags: typescript, next

Estoy creando una pagina de error para mi aplicacion de Next 14, y al mismo tiempo aprendiendo typescript.

```
// _error.tsx
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs";
import Error from "next/error";
import { NextPageContext } from "next";
import StyledComponentsLayout from "@/src/layouts/StyledComponentsLayout";

const CustomErrorComponent = (props: { statusCode: number }) => {
  return <Error statusCode={props.statusCode} />;
};

CustomErrorComponent.getInitialProps = async (contextData: NextPageContext) => {
  await Sentry.captureUnderscoreErrorException(contextData);

  return Error.getInitialProps(contextData);
};

CustomErrorComponent.Layout = StyledComponentsLayout;

export default CustomErrorComponent;
```

Funciona perfecto, pero si yo me llevo `CustomErrorComponent` fuera, y luego lo importo, no puedo acceder a `CustomErrorComponent.getInitialProps` y recibo el error:

`Property 'getInitialProps' does not exist on type '{ (props: { statusCode: number; }): Element; Layout: (page: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>) => ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>; }'.`

Con ayuda de Copilot logré que funcione, para ello tuve que crear una nueva interface

```
// _error.tsx
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs";
import Error from "next/error";
import { NextPageContext } from "next";
import CustomErrorComponent from "@/src/components/error/CustomErrorComponent";

interface CustomErrorComponentWithInitialProps {
  (props: { statusCode: number; }): JSX.Element;
  getInitialProps?: (contextData: NextPageContext) => Promise<any>;
}

const CustomErrorComponentWithProps: CustomErrorComponentWithInitialProps = CustomErrorComponent;

CustomErrorComponentWithProps.getInitialProps = async (contextData: NextPageContext) => {
  await Sentry.captureUnderscoreErrorException(contextData);

  return Error.getInitialProps(contextData);
};

export default CustomErrorComponent;
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: Por que al extraer el componente `CustomErrorComponent` ya no puedo acceder a `getInitialProps` y necesito crear una nueva interfaz? Es esto realmente necesario?

Comment: Parece que en otros casos te puede salir el error de que este definido como `any`, aunque usando TypeScript es preferente tener tipado (literalmente es su mayor ventaja), parece que en este caso TS no sabe que hay del otro lado, nunca he usado React o Next pero en Vue sucede lo mismo de que si no defines el tipo de los props te marca un error.